# I need a sample gRPC opentelemetry trace payload

Tags: postman, grpc, open-telemetry, open-telemetry-collector

I am looking for a way to send a open-telemetry trace payload to a deployed otel collector , this payload is to be sent on gRPC protocol.

I have been using postman rest client to send an  http request with a JSON payload on the url : localhost:55681/v1/traces , is something similar possible to do with gRPC.

Comment: I would say that you need to use your cuirrent JSON payload and protofiles https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-proto and GRPC in the postman (https://blog.postman.com/postman-now-supports-grpc/)  See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/76053188/3348604

Answer (score 1):

Something like the [otel-cli](https://github.com/equinix-labs/otel-cli) maybe?

Comment: this will work but is slighly complex , a simple gRPC payload with metadata details would suffice , a gRPC equivalent of : honeycomb.io/blog/test-span-opentelemetry-collector

Answer (score -1):

`OpenTelemetry` can use `grpc` or `http`. Encoding on `grpc` is `protobuf`. You have couple of options on `http`. You can send `proto-json` or just `json`. There are couple of differences between `proto-json` and `json`. Below is a sample `proto-json` that you can curl POST to an OpenTelemetry collector.

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST http://localhost:4318/v1/traces -d '$DATA'
```

Data is:

```
{
  "resourceSpans": [
    {
      "resource": {
        "attributes": [
          {
            "key": "deployment.environment",
            "value": { "stringValue": "stage" }
          },
          { "key": "service.name", "value": { "stringValue": "Foo App" } },
          { "key": "service.version", "value": { "stringValue": "v1.0.0" } },
          { "key": "telemetry.sdk.language", "value": { "stringValue": "go" } },
          {
            "key": "telemetry.sdk.name",
            "value": { "stringValue": "opentelemetry" }
          },
          {
            "key": "telemetry.sdk.version",
            "value": { "stringValue": "1.16.0" }
          }
        ]
      },
      "scopeSpans": [
        {
          "scope": { "name": "foo" },
          "spans": [
            {
              "traceId": "ba8c19fd8b342b534a8dc212573c4055",
              "spanId": "beeca1383d3dc369",
              "parentSpanId": "63087c13860db67e",
              "name": "LogOperation",
              "kind": 1,
              "startTimeUnixNano": "1697646563738900000",
              "endTimeUnixNano": "1697646563738927375",
              "links": [
                {
                  "traceId": "01000000000000000000000000000000",
                  "spanId": "0100000000000000",
                  "attributes": [
                    { "key": "one", "value": { "boolValue": true } },
                    { "key": "two", "value": { "boolValue": true } }
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "status": {}
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "schemaUrl": "https://opentelemetry.io/schemas/1.17.0"
    }
  ]
}
```